# Derivation for finding the coefficients of a Möbius transformation defined by three points

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, complex-geometry, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Somewhere on the internet (I don't quite remember where) I came across the following formulation for finding the four parameters $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ of a Möbius transformation given three points $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$ and their images $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$:

$$\left[\matrix{a & b \\ c & d}\right] = \left[\matrix{z_2-z_3 & z_1z_3-z_1z_2 \\ z_2-z_1 & z_1z_3-z_2z_3}\right]^{-1}\cdot\left[\matrix{w_2-w_3 & w_1w_3-w_1w_2 \\ w_2-w_1 & w_1w_3-w_2w_3}\right]$$

I am interested in learning how this expression was derived (if you have any proper references for this or the starting equations I used below, I would greatly appreciate it). I am starting from the [following equation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Specifying_a_transformation_by_three_points):

$$f_1(z)=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}$$

which is a Möbius transformation which maps $z_1\rightarrow0$, $z_2 \rightarrow1$, and $z_3\rightarrow\infty$. That's relatively easy to verify. Again, according to wikipedia, it is possible to express the coefficients of a Möbius transformation as a matrix:

$$\mathcal{H}=\left[\matrix{a & b \\c & d}\right]$$

from which we [can extract the Möbius transformation as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Projective_matrix_representations):

$$f(z)=[z,1]\left[\matrix{a & b \\c & d}\right]=[az+b,cz+d]=\left[\frac{az+b}{cz+d},1\right]$$

**First question**: I'm trying to make sense of this matrix representation. What exactly is going on here? The dot product makes sense, but what is that last operation? I could interpret this as some form of normalization in the second dimension, but if that were the case, why is there an equal sign between the unnormalized and normalized version? And why did we start from $[z,1]$?

Simply accepting this representation and moving on, it makes sense that we could also express the coefficients of that map above in terms of such a $2$-by-$2$ matrix (I can see how the dot product above returns the function $f_1$):

$$\mathcal{H}_1=\left[\matrix{z_2-z_3 & -z_1(z_2-z_3) \\ z_2-z_1 & -z_3(z_2-z_1)}\right]=\left[\matrix{z_2-z_3 & z_1z_3-z_1z_2 \\ z_2-z_1 & z_1z_3-z_2z_3}\right]$$

If we then do the same trick for a second set of points $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$, we obtain an equivalent matrix

$$\mathcal{H}_2=\left[\matrix{w_2-w_3 & -w_1(w_2-w_3) \\ w_2-w_1 & -w_3(w_2-w_1)}\right]=\left[\matrix{w_2-w_3 & w_1w_3-w_1w_2 \\ w_2-w_1 & w_1w_3-w_2w_3}\right]$$

I assume that the initial equation connects these two Möbius transformations through the map to $0$, $1$, and $\infty$, using the foward version $f_1(z)$ to map $z_1$, $z_2$, $z_3$ to $0$, $1$, and $\infty$, and the inverse $f_2^{-1}(w)$ to map $0$, $1$, and $\infty$ to $w_1$, $w_2$, $w_3$. Apparently, these two distinct operations can be simplified by taking the dot product of the coefficient matrices:

$$\mathcal{H}=\left[\matrix{a & b \\c & d}\right]=\mathcal{H}_1^{-1}\cdot\mathcal{H}_2=\left[\matrix{z_2-z_3 & z_1z_3-z_1z_2 \\ z_2-z_1 & z_1z_3-z_2z_3}\right]^{-1}\cdot\left[\matrix{w_2-w_3 & w_1w_3-w_1w_2 \\ w_2-w_1 & w_1w_3-w_2w_3}\right]$$

**Second question**: Why is this possible? A guess: Linear transformations can be expressed as matrices, and chained linear transformations can be simplified by chaining the matrices corresponding to these operations?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone with a more thorough background in complex algebra could double-check my reasoning and fill any gaps I have left. Since the Wikipedia article also doesn't really have any references, I would also really appreciate it if you had any references which explain where they obtained these expressions from.

Comment: I think you should read a bit of projective geometry

Comment: To help you in your search, the matrix formulation uses homogenous coordinates. Möbius transformations can be understood as maps from the protective complex line (= the Riemann sphere) to itself. In this context, it can be calculated by just applying the corresponding matrix to the homogenous coordinates. You can read up on homogenous coordinates on Wikipedia.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos: After skimming the corresponding Wikipedia article, this does indeed seem to be the first step in clearing up my confusion. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: I assume by "dot product of matrices" you simply mean matrix multiplication (which, as far as I know, no one calls a dot product). Indeed, composition of Mobius transformations corresponds to matrix multiplication (I mentioned this in an answer on one of your questions a couple weeks ago).